# Initializing immutable map with JS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to keep plain JS object inside a redux state (a very big response from some request). I have the following reducer:

```
function reducer(state = new Map(), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_ACTION:
      return state.merge({
        request: action.request
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The thing is that `action.request` is a very big recursive tree, and the merge operation is very slow. Also, it's not plain JS, but it gets converted to immutable. I noticed that simply returning new `Map` is much faster:

```
function reducer(state = new Map(), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_ACTION:
      return new Map({
        request: action.request
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The state here contains plain JS request field, it's fast, but - is this a good approach? Will the shallow compare inside redux connect still work?

Answer (score 0):

New keyword will always create a new object in the memory. Let's try, Previous state can be retain as follows:-

```
function reducer(state = new Map(), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_ACTION:
      let mergeStates = {...state,[action.stateIdentificationKey]:action.request}
      return state.merge(mergeStates);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

`stateIdentificationKey` is used to identify merged states. With every state you have to send a key for identification.

You can try this also:-

```
function reducer(state = new Map(), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_ACTION:
      return new Map({
           ...state,
        request: action.request
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```